# Aggregate unique values from multiple columns in R

Tags: r, concatenation, grouping, aggregation, large-data

I need to import a csv and in any case where the lines have all of the same data, except for only columns p and q, will have to combine those lines and put underscores between the values in p and q. The problem is there are about 40 columns to group. I'm trying R because the file size can be large and using something like powershell takes way too long to group. The code I tried seemed to work with 5 rows and 1 duplicate except those two columns but a larger data set failed to produce the results I want.

For example...and I'm taking out a lot columns in the below examples and my code example but hopefully you get the idea:

```
a, b, c, d, p,q
ab,1,no,id,ad,43  
ab,3,zq,id,7a,23
ac,4,as,79,8d,2s
ad,3,zq,id,86,25
ac,3,zq,id,7a,af
b4,7,as,93,zz,aw
b4,7,as,93,32,al
```

Needs to be like:

```
 a,b, c, d, p,q
ab,1,no,id,ad,43  
ab,3,zq,id,7a,23
ac,4,as,79,8d,2s
ad,3,zq,id,86_7a,25_af
b4,7,as,93,zz_32,aw_al
```

Below is what I tried with "dat" as the dataframe but it seems messy and the results seem to be skewing the format of the output CSV. q and p end up at the end of the file and will contain rows within rows of data and not aggregated column info.

```
 dat <- read.csv(file ="Sample.csv", header= TRUE)
 library(dplyr)
 result <- dat %>%
 group_by(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,r,x,w,y,z,aa,bb,cc,dd,ee) %>% 
 summarise(p = paste(p, collapse = "_"),q = paste(q, collapse = "_")) %>%
 ungroup()
 write.csv(result, "test.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

FYI- this is my first time using R.

Comment: Not clear why your code is not working.  DO you need `summarise_at(vars(p, q), paste, collapse="_")`

Comment: I think you should read this with `read.csv`. Might be easier to work with that way.

Comment: Sorry, I did read.csv and write, just didn't include that part. Edited the code.

Comment: @akrun , I may have figured out the formatting issue. I am starting to think what I have does actually work, however my .csv file sometimes contains double quotes as values. When I'm writing the csv again, it takes anything after that double quote and creates a sub row...trying to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: Not sure if it is a result of writing the data.  WHen you write data, try `write.csv(..., quote = FALSE)`.   If you have double quotes, then do `dat %>% mutate_if(is.character, str_remove, '"') %>%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to remove the double quotes if the column is `character`, then do the `group_by` `paste`

```
library(tidyverse)
nm1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
      "m", "n", "o", "r", "x", "w", "y", "z", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", 
       "ee")
dat %>% 
   mutate_if(is.character, str_remove, '"') %>%
   group_by_at(vars(nm1)) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(p, q), list(~ paste(unique(.), collapse="_")))
```

Comment: This helps too. The problem I'm having now is that each data is surrounded by double quotes and delimited by a comma:

"a","b","c"

sometimes input data will look like this:

" ,ab"," f"ss",    and seems to throw my output off.

Comment: @user481211  In that case, you can also use `separate_rows` with `sep=","`.  Without a small reproducible example, difficult to comment

Comment: edited my comment, accidentally pressed enter before I could complete the example.

Comment: @user481211  Can you update your post with a small reprod example using `dput` so thtat i becomes easier to understand your structure

Comment: I ended up changing the delimiter of the input file to pipes to get around the issue I was having. Seems to be working now, only issue is large data sets are still take too long to go through, though the time is about half of what it was with powershell.